# ConTeXt: External SVG images using XML setups

Tags: floats, context, svg, xml

## Background

Include an external SVG image from an HTML `img` element, using ConTeXt LMTX.

## Code

Here's `main.tex`:

```tex
\startbuffer[document]
<body><img src="circle.svg"/></body>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:xhtml
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{body|img}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:body
  \xmlflush{#1}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:img
  \placefigure{}{\externalfigure[circle.svg][conversion=mp]}
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:xhtml}

\starttext
  \xmlprocessbuffer{xhtml}{document}{}
\stoptext
```

Here's `circle.svg`:

```xml
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20"/></g>
</svg>
```

## Problem

When compiled using `context main.tex`, the PDF does not show a circle:

[image: Missing image]

## Question

How do you make the circle appear, rather than what appears to be unexecuted commands? (Without using Inkscape to convert the image.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the mailing-list, wrap the figures in `texcode`:

```tex
\startxmlsetups xml:img
  \starttexcode
    \placefigure{}{%
      \externalfigure[\xmlatt{#1}{src}][conversion=mp]%
    }
  \stoptexcode
\stopxmlsetups
```